# "navigator is not defined" in app bundled with rollup

Tags: commonjs, rollupjs

One of my strict Node.js applications works perfectly when run during development.
Now I successfully bundled it with `rollup` but trying to run the bundled js gives:
`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`.
I'm trying to discover who is calling `navigator` in a Commonjs file but without success so far (too many packages) but seems related to same debug code.
Sure I'm missing something. BTW I cannot use the obvious `cjs` format because: `RollupError: Module format "cjs" does not support top-level await. Use the "es" or "system" output` formats rather. Also `system` format has missing variables.
Anyone could enlighten me?
My `rollup.confing.js` contains:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";

export default {
    input: "prepare.ts",
    output: {
        file: "../dist/prepare.js",
        format: "es",
        sourcemap: false,
        banner: "#! /usr/bin/env node\n",
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve({preferBuiltins: true}),
        json(),
        commonjs({transformMixedEsModules: true}),
        terser(),
        typescript({outputToFilesystem: true, sourceMap: false}),
    ]
};
```

Thanks!
mario

Comment: Also changing the format to `cjs`, wrapping the top-level await in a self-called function (that makes the bundling succeeded) and changing the resulting file to `../dist/prepare.cjs` at runtime I have again the `navigator not defined` error. Seems like rollup does not includes some package that mock `navigator` in a pure node application.

Comment: Solved the dirty way. At the end of the output.banner I have added `\n const navigator = {};\n`. BTW, the plugin `rollup-plugin-entry-code-injector` does not inject anything, i.e., it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the config:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
     ...
     resolve({ exportConditions: ['node'] }), 
  ]
}
```